# How to compare an array loaded from file with another array loaded from another file c#

Tags: c#, arrays, file, split, compare

I have to do a program in C# Form, which has to load from a file which looks something like that:

100ACTGGCTTACACTAATCAAG

101TTAAGGCACAGAAGTTTCCA

102ATGGTATAAACCAGAAGTCT

...

120GCATCAGTACGTACCCGTAC

20 lines formed with a number (ID) and 20 letters (ADN); the other file looks like that:

TGCAACGTGTACTATGGACC

In few words, this is a game where a murder is done, there are 20 people; i have to load and split the letters and.. i have to compare them and in the end i have to find the best match. 
I have no idea how to do that, I don't know how to load the letters in the array and then to split them.. and then to compare them.

Comment: Does ID have a fixed length? Does it always have 3 digits? Or is your problem more on the "how to compare" case?

Comment: Yes it does, there are only 20 lines so it's only 100-120

Comment: The simplest "match function" would be to compute a score based on the number of "letters" that correspond, i.e. that fall on the same position. For every entry in your "suspect" file, you would iterate the DNA sequence and compare each letter with the one at the corresponding index in the "evidence" sequence. If the letters match, it's a `HIT`, increment `count` with one. The `match score` would then be the percentage of the `count` with respect to `20` (the total number of letters in the sequence. I don't know much about DNA matching rules, but I guess you could also match on "subregions".

Comment: Well the logic of the program i know it myself, but i don't know to "code" it :D

Answer (score 0):

This is a **simple** `match function`. It might not be of the complexity your game requires. This solution does not require an explicit `split` on the strings in order to get an array of DNA "letters". The DNA is compared `in place`.

Compare each "suspect" entry to the "evidence one.

```
int idLength = 3;
string evidence = //read from file
List<string> suspects = //read from file
List<double> matchScores = new List<double>();

foreach (string suspect in suspects)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = idLength; i < suspect.Length; i++)
    {
        if (suspect[i + idLength] == evidence[i]) count++;
    }
    matchScores.Add(count * 100 / evidence.Length);
}
```

The `matchScores` list now contains all the individual match scores. I did not save the maximum match score in a separate variable as there can be several "suspects" with the same score. To find out which subject has the best match, just iterate the `matchScores` list. The index of the best match is the index of the suspect in the `suspects` list.

Optimization notes:

- you could check each "suspect" string to see where (i.e. at what index does) the DNA sequence starts, as it could be variable;
- a dictionary could be used here, instead of two lists, with the "suspect string" as key and the match score as value

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do here, is use something like a calculation of the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between the strings.

In simple terms, that provides a count of how many single letters you have to change for a string to become equal to another. In the context of DNA or Proteins, this can be interpreted as representing the number of mutations between two individuals or samples. A shorter distance will therefore indicate a closer relationship between the two.

The algorithm can be fairly heavy computationally, but will give you a good answer. It's also quite fun and enlightening to implement. You can find a couple of ways of implementing it under the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Recursive).

If you find it challenging to understand how it works, I recommend you set up an example grid by hand, with one short string horizontally along the top, and one vertically along the left side, and try going through the calculations manually, just to understand the concept properly (it can be confusing at first, but is really not that difficult).